# Shallow Copy - Reference type anomalous nature

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

I cannot understand the output of the two sets of code snippets given below.
How don't really get the concept of shallow copy. How can it be explained?

Class:

```
 public class Person : ICloneable
 {
    public string Name;        
    public int[] arr; 
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
 }
```

Code Snippet 1:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "Name1";
        p1.arr = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5 };
        Person p2 = (Person)p1.Clone();

        p1.Name = "Name2";
        p1.arr[0] = 11;

        Console.WriteLine(p2.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(p2.arr[0].ToString());
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Output:
Name1
11

Doubt: Isn't string a reference type. Then why p2.Name is printed as "Name1" in snippet 1

Code Snippet 2:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "Name1";
        p1.arr = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Person p2 = (Person)p1.Clone();

        p1.Name = "Name2";
        p1.arr = new int[5] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

        Console.WriteLine(p2.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(p2.arr[0].ToString());
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Output:
Name1
1

Comment: Completely offtopic and probably inappropiate, but I felt an overwhelming need to add a black-mesa tag to the question... :)

Answer (score 4):

The int[] array in your example is a reference type. That means, that both `p1.arr` and `p2.arr` point to the same array in memory.

If you change the value of the first index of `p1.arr`, this means that the value of the first index of `p2.arr` is also changed. Hence, the behaviour in code snippet 1.

The difference in the second code snippet, is that you change the *reference* to the array of p1. Now, `p1.arr` is a reference to a new object. `p2.arr` still holds a reference to the 'original' array. Thus, printing `p2.arr[0]` prints 1.

**EDIT**:

To hopefully take away some doubt, maybe it is clearer if you remember that typing:

```
p1.Name = "Name2";
```

is actually:

```
p1.Name = new String("Name2");
```

This is exactly the same as with your int[] array. You are not changing the value of `p1.Name`, you are creating a new string object, and *changing the reference* of p1.Name to this new string object. p2.Name still holds its own reference to the 'original' string object, namely 'Name1'. By changing the reference of `p1.Name`, *that* reference does not change.

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed. If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

To alleviate your doubt in the original question.

String is indeed a reference type, The thing to remember is that what you are doing to the array and what you are doing to the string are not the same.

```
p1.Name = "Name2"; // new String -equivalent to p1.Name = new string("Name2")
p1.arr[0] = 11; //updated array element
```

For the array you are are changing the data in piece of memory referenced.  For the String you are creating a new string ( at a new memory location) and making p1.Name ,the reference, point to that newly allocated memory. p2.Name (which is a different reference)  remains pointing at the original memory location where the characters "Name1" are stored

As an aside because of the *immutability* of string  there is no way a change to p1.Name will show up in p2.Name.  Any attempt to change the string ,such as string.replace, will create a new string in memory.

hope that helps.

Comment: hi, i think you should have put the line
 p1.arr[0] = 11;
for the explanation. Otherwise it may be misleading.

Comment: i meant your code snippet line p1.arr = new int[5] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }; //updated array
doesn't go with your explanation

Comment: Thanks Mahatma, you are correct of course  I copied the array update snippet from the wrong part of the OPs  post.

Answer (score 0):

Pls see inline comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.Name = "Name1";
    p1.arr = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5 };
    Person p2 = (Person)p1.Clone();

    p1.Name = "Name2"; //Now p1.Name points to a new memory location
    //But p2.Name is still pointing to the location p1.Name had
    // originally pointed to.

    p1.arr[0] = 11; //here p1.arr and p2.arr are pointing to the same place
    //So since you are changing the value of one location it gets 
    //reflected in both

    Console.WriteLine(p2.Name); //Prints Name1
    Console.WriteLine(p2.arr[0].ToString()); //Prints 11
    Console.Read();

}
```

In the second snippet when you say

```
p1.arr = new int[5] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
```

p1.arr is made to point to an entirely new location. (like  what happens when you do p1.Name = "Name2") So it is not getting reflected on p2.arr which is still pointing to the same place p1.arr was previously pointing to. (i.e to  the array {1,2,3,4,5})